# Can you add a link to a ERC-721

Tags: erc-721

I would like to get your though about what would be the best way to encapsulate a document in the blockchain.
What i would like to achieve is that 1 token = 1 document, this token isn't divisible, and you can hence transfer the ownership of this document, by sending this token.

Is it possible for a ERC721 token to store a IFPS link ?

Let say i have 1000 documents, and i would like to create a smartcontract, which say if you send ETH in return you get one token which is a link to a unique document (you then own this document), does it sound feasible ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the ERC-721 specification specifically allows attaching a document to each token. Please see the metadata extension in the standard at https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721

One caveat, and maybe this is a subtlety. The token points to the document, but the document might not point to the token. People will need to recognize that you (your contract) are the authority on tokenizing this document.